# Foam particles: Realflow to Blender

Tags: particles, import, fluid-simulation

is there any reasonable way to import foam particles from Realflow to Blender (and satisfyingly render them in Cycles afterwards)? Foam converted to mesh works but it's far from perfect. I don't mind any crazy workaround solutions, everything than might work (additional After Effects compositing, other software use etc.)

I am thinking about learning Cinema from scratch just because of Realflow integration. Unless there is a solution that works with Blender, but I was unable to find anything so far.

Comment: There was a [patch](https://developer.blender.org/T41935) allowing to import .bin files from Realflow which was deprecated since then due to implementing Alembic import. So try to use that in this Realflow - Blender case.

Comment: I haven't even thought about exporting particles as .abc. I was convinced that alembic works for meshes only! But I tried and it works. At least somehow. The question is, what to do with them now? When imported to blender, RF particles essentially convert to vertices. Can a material be assigned to them? I rendered an animation in openGL and edited it in AE. Now compositing is an option, which is much better than nothing. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5Bk90wXuos&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Rendering particles in Eevee or Cycles - posted by user "opis" on effectivetds.com forum: 1 / import alembic (do not forget in preference - cogwheel - check "is sequence") 1 / create an object that will be instantiated (which will replace the points)
2/ select this object - shift select frame 1 of the alembic
3 / ctrl + P - parent to object
4/ select particles
5 / click object properties (orange square) / instancing / Verts